# Add a line in between two lines in a file from bash

Tags: bash, macos, search, replace, sed

I have file named `user.rb` as like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I want to add a new line and after adding line it will look :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Company
end
```

But I want to add this additional line from bash script or terminal.
 I tried it with this bash code:

```
sed -i '' 's/end/include Company\n\end/' app/models/user.rb
```

But it does not return new line after adding line.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OSX you can use this `sed` command:

```
sed -i.bak '/ApplicationRecord$/,/^end$/{/end$/i\
include Company
}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`, append (`a`) the desired portion after match (here i am matching `< ApplicationRecord` at the end of the line):

```
sed '/<[[:blank:]]*ApplicationRecord$/a\    include Company' file.rb
```

To edit the file in-place with original one backed up with a `.bak` extension:

```
sed -i.bak '/<[[:blank:]]*ApplicationRecord$/a\    include Company' file.rb
```

Without any backup:

```
sed -i '' '/<[[:blank:]]*ApplicationRecord$/a\    include Company' file.rb
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.rb 
class User < ApplicationRecord
end

$ sed '/<[[:blank:]]*ApplicationRecord$/a\    include Company' file.rb 
class User < ApplicationRecord
    include Company
end
```